# How to get value from a specific row and column in MS ACCESS database?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

First, I don't have unique value to directly point out a value I want to retrieve, so there for, I cannot use the `WHERE` Statement. The reason for that, because I have a database where I constantly updated or deleted, so if I use `WHERE` statement I have to edit the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Then do apply a unique value - add a field of data type *AutoNumber* or you will never get out of this mess.